# Importing the Private Key from the .pfx file

Tags: c#, encryption, certificate, key, private

How can I import the private key of a certificate from a .pfx file?  I have this code:

```
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("C:/amazon.pfx", "hello", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        string private_key = cert.PrivateKey.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(private_key);
```

However, the output is:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
```

How can I get the private key in string format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but the MSDN documentation says that you're getting the private key with the following code

```
string private_key = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(false);
Console.WriteLine(private_key);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey.aspx